# PHP returns only the first row from table

Tags: php, sql, rows

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password");
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "database");
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
$numeUser = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from table order by column_name");
$utilizator = mysqli_fetch_array($numeUser);
$numeUtilizator = $column_name[1];
$nume = $column_name[2];
$rol = $column_name[5];
$actiune = $column_name[8];

    $firstNames = $numeUtilizator;

    $lastNames = $nume;

    $productNames = $rol;

    $actions = $actiune;

    $data = array();
    $i=0;
    while($i < count($firstNames))
    {
      $row["firstname"] = $firstNames;
      $row["lastname"] = $lastNames;
      $row["productname"] = $productNames;
      $row["quantity"] = $actions;
      $data[$i] = $row;
      $i++;
    }

    header("Content-type: application/json"); 
    echo "{\"data\":" .json_encode($data). "}";
?>
```

I have the code above and I can`t figure why it returns me only the first row  from database. It does not show them all. Does anyone please what am I missing?

Thank you very much. Cheers!

Comment: That looks more like PHP than like Javascript

Comment: *"Javascript returns only the first row from table"* There is no JavaScript, at all, in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I am using Javascript on another page which calls this script.

Comment: Java ? Sigh... BTW look at where you create the $row array

Comment: @BogdanConstantinescu: *"I am using Java on another page which calls this script"* That seems unlikely. You're probably using *JavaScript* on the other page. Java is an entirely different language, used in an entirely different environment.

Comment: Which version of php are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A part from the fact that there is no javascript but php.

The mysql_fetch_array (deprecated, no longer exist in php 7) needs to be called in a while loop, look at the documentation, there is your problem, you're only fetching the 1st row.

Another thing, that code is messy, search google for model view controller or model view presenter.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use SELECT * when querying, only select the columns you are going to use.